# Copy Paste Values If Value = X

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to write a code that moves a row from one sheet to another when a value in one the columns is changed. For testing purposes, it reads that if the cell in column 13 reads "Test", then that row is deleted from the original sheet and moved into the new sheet, "TestSheet". However, I'm trying to get the row thats moved into the new one to be pasted as values, but when I try to include the Pastespecial, it shows errors.

This is my code as it stands

```
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet_master()
For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(13).Cells
If myCell.Value = "Test" Then
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
myCell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure I need to include "PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues" somewhere, but everywhere I try to include it, it seems to not work.

Comment: Instead of looping, simply use autofilter as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207)

Comment: Please show the actual code that you use to paste into the other worksheet, and the exact error messages that it produces. 
You could produce the macro via the macro recording feature of Excel, by recording each step as you do this manually, you may be able to find the solution yourself.

Comment: This essentially the exact same code I use, and I cant save what I have because the line with the Copy and Paste turns red and says "Compile error: Expected: end of statement" when I try to add the ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" to the end of line 4

Comment: '''
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet_test()
For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(13).Cells
If myCell.Value = "Test" Then
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
myCell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
'''

Is what I try and I get the error mentioned above. It works completely fine without the ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" text. But I need it to paste as values

Comment: If you define the target in the `Copy` method don't need `Paste`. What is `emptyrow`? If it is not defined it is `0` and gives an error.

Comment: I swapped out emptyrow for Rows.Count, will edit now

Comment: I think I solved it my own, I just had to put the Copy and Paste on separate lines and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Asof @BigBen comment rephrased the answer.

The faulty code is that if you want to copy the entire row, but the target is not cover an entire row. Therefore try this:

```
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).EntireRow
```

If you want to paste in the first empty row use the `Offset`

```
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

If in the original range there are formulas and you need only the values either use only absolute references, or cannot directly copy/paste the range. Then as you solved has to use `PasteSpecial`

```
myCell.EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: The way I did it originally managed to work, but I tried your way as well and it also worked! I'm not well versed in VBA code at all, is there any major difference between the two? Or anything your solution offers that my current setup doesn't? 

Also - Lets say I wanted the original prompt, to send rows with "Test" in column 13 to "TestSheet", but I also wanted to send rows with "Test2" in column 13 to "TestSheet2" and rows with "Test3" in column 13 to "TestSheet3"? Would I just copy paste the original code back to back with different parameters and a "next" in between them?

Comment: There are no essential difference, the use of the constant names and explicit expressions are more understandable for others.  The simplest way seems to use `ElseIf` sg. like this: `If myCell.Value = "Test" Then -part1- ElseIf myCell.Value = "Test2" Then -part2- ElseIf myCell.Value = "Test3" Then -part3- Else -part4- End If`

Comment: Ah thank you! Ill try that with "ElseIf". If I were to use the code you suggested, where would you put the ElseIf? Would it just replace the "If" in line 5?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet_master()
   Dim myCell As Range, ToDelete As Range
   Set ToDelete = Range("A" & Rows.Count)  ' initialize ToDelete
   For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(13).Cells
      If myCell.Value = "Test" Then
         Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).EntireRow.Value = myCell.EntireRow.Value
         Set ToDelete = Union(ToDelete, myCell)
      End If
   Next myCell
   ToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. If you want to copy values it's better to set destination values than to copy and paste.
2. If your `For Each` loop is from the beginning to the end and you delete rows during this loop you miss rows. Typically we should do it in the reverse order. But you need to have your copied rows without reversing.
   So you can save cells to be deleted in a separate range and afterwards delete all rows at once.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I've copied from the original code.

Comment: For OP: `(2)` would be much clearer if you used `.Offset`.

Comment: Again, I used notation of OP. For me it is clear, means next row and is shorter than `.Offset(1)`.